# ScalaTest test name without fixture?

Tags: scala, scalatest

First off, I saw it and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831246/access-scalatest-test-name-from-inside-test) sounds exactly like what I need except for one thing, I can't use fixture.TestDataFixture because I can't extend fixture.FreeSpecLike, and I am sure that there must be *some* way to get the test name in a way that looks more like this (imagined code that doesn't compile)

```
class MySpec extends FlatSpecLike with fixture.TestDataFixture {
  "this technique" - {
     "should work" in { 
      assert(testData.name == "this technique should work")
    }
    "should be easy" in { td =>
      assert(testData.name == "this technique should be easy")
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I just can't believe something like this is not possible :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And found an answer(well a collegue did), not sure I like it but works:

on the trait that other tests depend on

```
class MySpec extends FlatSpecLike {
//... other stuff
    var testName = "UndefinedTestName"
    override def withFixture (test: NoArgTest) :Outcome= {
       testName = test.name
       super.withFixture(test)
   }
}
```

simple solution but rather obscure, also I wonder if anyone sees any problems with it

Answer (score 4):

While you already came to basically this solution, here is a safer variation:

```
private val _currentTestName = new ThreadLocal[String]

override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
  _currentTestName.set(test.name)
  val outcome = super.withFixture(test)
  _currentTestName.set(null)
  outcome
}

protected def currentTestName: String = {
  val testName = _currentTestName.get()
  assert(testName != null, "currentTestName should only be called in a test")
  testName
}
```

Alternately,

```
protected def currentTestName = Option(_currentTestName.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find sequence of test names using method testNames in FlatSpecLike trait:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike

class FooSpec extends FlatSpecLike {

  it should "check case one" in {
    println("test some code ...")

    println(testNames.mkString("\n"))
    /*
      prints:
      should check case one
      should check case two
    */
    // ...
    assert(1 == 1)
    println("end.")
  }

  it should "check case two" in {
    println("test some code ...")

    assert(1 == 1)
    println("end.")
  }
}
```

and find each you needed. Hope it helps.